# Correct way to Office.initialize in Office add-ins with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-app

I want to build an Office add-in with angular and angular-ui-router. I don't know what's the correct place to put `Office.initialize`.

At the moment, I use in `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/devote/HTML5-History-API/master/history.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
...
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
```

And `angularApp.js`:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
        })
    });
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])

app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('ttt', {
            url: '/ttt',
            template: 'ttt',
            controller: 'tttCtrl'
        })
        .state('addinTest', {
            url: '/addin/test',
            template: '<a href="ttt" target="_self">ttt</a><br/><br/><a href="addin/another" target="_self">another page</a>'
        })
}])

app.controller('tttCtrl', [function() {
    console.log('console ttt')
}])
```

And `manifest.xml`:

```
<bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/addin/test" />
```

So loading the add-in shows `test` page with 2 buttons. Clicking on `ttt` loads `ttt` page. **However, my test shows that `console ttt` is displayed twice.**

If I remove `angular.element(document).ready(...)` from `Office.initialize`, `console ttt` is correctly displayed only once. However, when opening `another` page which interacts with Excel, I got an error: `Office.context is undefined`.

So could anyone tell me if we should use `angular.bootstrap(...)`? And what's the correct way to do `Office.initialize` in Office add-in with angularjs? Many random odd behaviours occur because of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why console ttt is displayed twice, is I have `<body ng-app="myApp">` and angular.bootstrap at the same time.

> If I remove angular.element(document).ready(...) from Office.initialize, console ttt is correctly displayed only once. However, when opening another page which interacts with Excel, I got an error: Office.context is undefined.

I have not tested, but removing the `Office.initialize` block completely and keeps `<body ng-app="myApp">` may fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is you must manual start your AngularJS App inside Office.initialize

> RouteConfig.js

```
Office.initialize = function () {
    //load angular app after office has been initialized
    angular.bootstrap($('#TSRApp'), ['TSRApp']);
}
var app = angular.module("TSRApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "../Home/Index.html"
        })
        .when("/settings", {
            templateUrl: "../Settings/Index.html"
        })
        .when("/message", {
            templateUrl: "../MessageRead/MessageRead.html"
        });
});
```